# Does docker buildkit work with a mounted docker.sock and docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-in-docker, docker-buildkit

I am trying to start sibling containers from inside a countainer with a mounted docker.sock.  The container can start simple sibling containers without issue, but when using the docker-compose script, it fails with:

```
=> [internal] load build definition from demo.dockerfile                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3865249966/demo.dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

demo.dockerfile is the dockerfile I am trying to build images from, referenced from the docker-compose file.

Has anyone used docker-compose with buildkit and a mounted docker.sock before?

It's like that pathing is getting messed up for finding the dockerfile.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  I'd expect this approach to work but without seeing any of the code or setup it's hard to say why it isn't.

Comment: Hi, we figured it out and I've written a blog post that ill put as an answer soon.  The issue was the volume mount paths in the compose file were expanding to absolute paths INSIDE the container where docker-compose was running but of course, needed to work OUTSIDE on the host machine.  We passed in $(pwd) as an environment variable to the container and then inserted that path into the docker-compose file. Works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's what was happening:

The volume mount paths
in our docker-compose file broke, because these were expanding to absolute paths *inside* the job-runner but were running *outside* on the
host machine.  We couldn't just fix it by hardcoding the paths because everyone's machine and CI are all different.

As a workaround we pass the base-path aka working directory as an environment variable into the job-runner when we start it up like this:

```sh
docker run -e HOST_MACHINE_PWD=$(pwd) -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock job-runner
```

Then we read that in our script that generates the docker-compose file and use it as the base path for mounting those volumes.
The fact that we were already generating our docker-compose config dynamically made it easier, and if you're using a static config,
you may have to try your luck with `sed` or some other way of overwriting the docker-compose path.

Here's the blog post we wrote explaining this fix and our setup, with links to the source code for anyone else trying to do something like this: https://www.lunasec.io/docs/blog/lunasec-ci/#how-to-use-dockersock-and-docker-compose-together